# JFileChooser FileNameExtensionFilfter inconsistency on Mac vs Windows

Tags: java, macos, swing, jfilechooser

I'm writing a java program involving JFileChooser. It works perfectly on my Windows 8.1 laptop, but on my friends Mac the default fileFilter isn't the image files filter. It can be selected as an option from the little dropdown menu of file filters, but it's not the default, so the user can select other file types and break the code. Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
FileSelect = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter j = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files", "jpg", "png");
FileSelect.addChoosableFileFilter(j);
FileSelect.setFileFilter(j);
FileSelect.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);   
FileSelect.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);  
int fileresult = FileSelect.showOpenDialog(FileSelect);
if (fileresult == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
Files = FileSelect.getSelectedFiles();
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce of Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Mac OS X 10.10.3 with jdk 1.8.0_31.